# Question on terminology

Tags: terminology

If a map $M$ has the feature
$$
M(x+y)=M(y)M(x)
$$
is there a term to describe this kind of map? It's not a linear map, at least. The order matters here - $M(y)M(x) \neq M(x)M(y)$.

Comment: You can't have $M(y)M(x)\neq M(x)M(y)$, because that would imply that $M(x+ y)\neq M(y + x)$, and that violates either what we want functions to be, or what we (usually) want addition to be.

Comment: But what if we have a function on the set of ordinal numbers: Then we have $\omega+1 \neq 1+\omega$, so what's the problem since each of those $2$ ordinals may have an image?

Comment: @Matti: Can you clarify if your question is about arbitrary (possibly non-commutative) addition/multiplication or not? Or is it just about functions from $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$? Do you assume continuity?

Comment: @MartinR I asked this question over two years ago. It's been answered already. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its name is an exponential map.

Answer (score 2):

A map $M: A \to B$ with the property that
$$
\forall x, y \in A: M(x+y)=M(x)M(y) \tag{*}
$$
is called a [group homomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_homomorphism) from the (additive) group $(A, +)$ to the (multiplicative) group $(B, \cdot)$. Example:
$$
 M : \Bbb C \to \Bbb C,  z \mapsto e^{\operatorname{Re}(z)}.
$$

Your condition
$$
\forall x, y \in A: M(x+y)=M(y)M(x) \tag{**}
$$
is equivalent to $(*)$ if $(A, +)$ is commutative (i.e. $A$ is an abelian group), as mentioned in the comments. I am not aware of a term for $(**)$ in the non-commutative case.

---

In the particular case that $A=B= \Bbb R$, $(*)$ is equivalent to $f = \log M$ being an [additive function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_map) on $\Bbb R$, i.e. it satisfies [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation)
$$ 
\forall x, y \in \Bbb R: f(x+y)=f(x) + f(y) \, .
$$
This functional equation has [nonlinear solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation#Existence_of_nonlinear_solutions_over_the_real_numbers), but under some conditions (i.e. continuity) it follows that $f(x) = cx$ for some constant $c$. So in this special case we have that $M$ is an exponential function: $M(x) = e^{cx}$.

Comment: The term you seek is "antihomomorphism".